# Find TIMESTAMP format in Python

Tags: python, timestamp

This is my time stamp which I mentioned below,
can someone tell me how to what is the format of it?

`date_time_str = '2017-08-24T05:16:36.085Z date_time_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_time_str, '%Y-%m-%d T%H:%M:%S.%f')`

I tried this one, it gives error.

2nd question,

As a Type of `date_time_str` is `STRING`, can we make it to `TIMESTAMP`?

is it possible in python?

because I want to add it into SQL as it needs type as "TIMESTAMP".

Thanks.

Comment: Did either of the answers below help you? If not, please follow-up specifically so any outstanding concerns can be addressed. If so, please [accept one of the answers.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need to add a timestamp value to a TIMESTAMP field in sql you can do this.

```
import datetime

my_timestamp = datetime.datetime.now()
```

update your db with something like this...

```
f"UPDATE my_sql_table
SET Timfield = {my_timestamp} where id = 1"
```

Comment: Does this answer your question?

Comment: Yes, it is ans of the ques